How to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file, while keeping stdout and stderr to a display?
Assume a shell script that has output to both stdout and stderr. While keeping their outputs to display without merging them (not 2>&1), I'd like a single file that contains both its stdout and stderr. How can I achieve this behavior?
What I'd tried.
$ ./test.sh | tee test.log

-> Only stdout is written to a file.
$ ./test.sh 1> >(tee stdout.txt >&1) 2> >(tee stderr.txt >&2)

-> I want a single file that contains stdout and stderr output, while keeping stdout and stderr stream separated to a display.
$ ./test.sh 2> >(tee -a out.txt) 1>>out.txt

-> Only display stderr
Associated questions by system doesn't solve my question. I need to keep stdout and stderr separated. There is the answer in BashFAQ/106 "Complex duplicate logging". Thank you tjm3772.

You might only need tee because this command puts it in the file and still displays it to stdout: df -h | tee disk_usage.txt

As there is a module that needs to read only stderr, I can't combine as 2>&1.

Perhaps see BashFAQ/106 (especially "Complex duplicate logging")

Thank you tjim3772 !!! This is what I want to do.

Or maybe this answer
